# Count elements across users in df after grouping by, in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, group-by, aggregate

I have this df:

```
|User     |country|
|   Ron   |  italy| 
|   Tom   |  japan|
|   Lin   |  spain|
|   Tom   |  china|
|   Tom   |  china|
|   Lin   |  japan|
|   Tom   |  china|
|   Lin   |  japan|
```

I want to count for each user the total amount of his countries.
for example, for the df above I'll get:

```
[Ron ->  [italy ->1], Tom -> [Japan -> 1, china -> 3], Lin -> [Spain -> 1, Japan ->2]]
```

I started with

```
val groupedbyDf = df.groupBy("User")
```

But I don't know how to continue.. agg() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create maps after group by, using relevant map functions:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("User", "country")
  .count()
  .groupBy("User")
  .agg(map(
      col("User"), 
      map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(col("country"), col("count"))))
      ).as("result")
  )
  .select("result")

df2.show(false)
+---------------------------------+
|result                           |
+---------------------------------+
|[Tom -> [china -> 3, japan -> 1]]|
|[Lin -> [spain -> 1, japan -> 2]]|
|[Ron -> [italy -> 1]]            |
+---------------------------------+
```

If you want all of them in one row, you can do one more aggregation:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("User", "country")
  .count()
  .groupBy("user")
  .agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(col("country"), col("count")))).as("result"))
  .agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(col("user"), col("result")))).as("result_all"))

df2.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|result_all                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[Tom -> [china -> 3, japan -> 1], Lin -> [spain -> 1, japan -> 2], Ron -> [italy -> 1]]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```